# Responsive Site appeare on iphone very small

Tags: responsive-design, responsive

I am working on a new website and trying to get it responsive.
But because of some reason the website appears very small if I test it with the browser inspect on a size of an iPhone, but if I change the window size in the browser to a custom width it acts normal.
If I test it on my own phone it also appears very small.

I appologize for the less information, but I really don't know where this problem is coming from.
Does someone have a hint for me?
This is the site: http://dev-ghp.whocando.eu/template/templates/main.html

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the mobile device to adjust its viewport for its screen size. Add this to the top of your `<head>`.

```
<meta name=viewport content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
```